# libboost-dev cannot install due to circular dependency

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, dependencies

Installing libboost-dev on Ubuntu 12.04:

System is offline due to unchangeable circumstances, so I have to download libraries and install manually using 'dpkg'.

[Ubuntu package repository shows that libboost-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-dev) for 12.04 is 1.48.0.2, and relies on "libboost1.46-dev"

I have another system, online, with identical setup, that I queried to find out which libboost-dev package is installed.  This confirms the 1.48.02:

```
 ~$ dpkg -l libboost-dev
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                                     Description
+++-===========================================-===========================================-======================================================================================================
ii  libboost-dev                                1.48.0.2                                    Boost C++ Libraries development files (default version)
```

So I downloaded the two packages, copied them manually to the offline system,

```
libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1
libboost-dev_1.48.0.2
```

and tried to install:

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i libboost*
dpkg: considering removing libboost1.48-dev in favour of libboost1.46-dev ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of libboost1.48-dev (--auto-deconfigure will help):
libboost-timer1.48-dev depends on libboost1.48-dev (= 1.48.0-3)
libboost1.48-dev is to be removed.
dpkg: regarding libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb containing libboost1.46-dev:
libboost1.48-dev conflicts with libboost1.46-dev
libboost1.46-dev (version 1.46.1-7ubuntu3) is to be installed.
dpkg: error processing libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
conflicting packages - not installing libboost1.46-dev
(Reading database ... 217276 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libboost-dev 1.48.0.2 (using libboost-dev_1.48.0.2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libboost-dev ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-dev:
libboost-dev depends on libboost1.46-dev; however:
Package libboost1.46-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libboost-dev (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libboost-dev
```

'dpkg' first considers replacing what seems to be the installed 1.48, but then can't because so many things depends on it.  It then says "libboost1.48-dev conflicts with libboost1.46-dev".

My online system shows that both packages are installed, but my offline system won't install, and that the package has only been unpacked:

```
 ~$ dpkg -l libboost-dev
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                                     Description
+++-===========================================-===========================================-======================================================================================================
iU  libboost-dev                                1.48.0.2                                    Boost C++ Libraries development files (default version)
```

What is wrong, that dpkg cannot install this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more poking around on this.

I don't know how (since this system is offline), but the libboost*1.48 packages were all installed in prohibiting the installation of the libboost1.46 packages (which are the 12.04 standard install).

As all I wanted were the standard install packages, I executed:

```
sudo dpkg -r libboost-*1.48.-dev
sudo dpkg -i libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubunut3_amd64.deb libboost-dev_1.48.0.2_amd64.deb
```

This completed the install successfully